# delayed effect of Range.activateAsCurrentCell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My apps script is iterating over matching cells, and on each iteration of the loop calls `curRange.activateAsCurrentCell()`, followed by `ui.alert(message)`.

Surprisingly, the current cell doesn't get activated until the user has clicked Yes/No on the alert. I tried inserting Utilities.sleep(1000), but it did not help.

Any ideas how to fix this ?

```
var textFinder = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('2023').getRange('C1:C')
      .createTextFinder('hello')
      .matchEntireCell(true)
      .matchCase(false)
      .matchFormulaText(false)
      .ignoreDiacritics(true);
var r = textFinder.findNext();
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
while (r != null) {
  r.activateAsCurrentCell();
  var result = ui.alert('Found a match. Continue Yes/No ?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO)
  if (result != ui.Button.YES) {
    return;
  }
  r = textFinder.findNext();
}
```

Comment: Please share the full code and sample/copy of your spreadsheet so we are able to replicate what you have. Remove sensitive data if any.

Comment: Updated the snippet include the entire code fragment.

Comment: Try adding `SpreadsheetApp.flush();` right after the cell activation call.

Comment: @doubleunary I think that your comment is an answer to this question. I would like to recommend posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `SpreadsheetApp.flush();` right after the cell activation call, like this:

```js
  // ...
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  let cell;
  while (cell = textFinder.findNext()) {
    cell.activateAsCurrentCell();
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    const response = ui.alert('Found a match. Continue?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
    if (response !== ui.Button.YES) {
      return;
    }
  }
  // ...
```

See [SpreadsheetApp.flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush).